# CMAKE_LIBRARY_ARCHITECTURE resets when passed via toolchain or command line

Tags: cmake

I have a couple of libs compiled for different architectures (x86, x86_64, amrv7...etc) in a directory structure like shown below:

```
(prefix)
|-> lib
    |-> x86
    |-> x86_64
    |-> ...
```

The intention is to set `CMAKE_LIBRARY_ARCHITECTURE` using a toolchain file. However cmake is resetting this variable and is not even found in `CMakeCache.txt`.

The example toolchain file is shown below:

```
set(CMAKE_C_COMPILER clang)
set(CMAKE_CXX_COMPILER clang++)
set(CMAKE_C_FLAGS "-m64")
set(CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS "-m64")
set(CMAKE_LIBRARY_ARCHITECTURE x86_64)
```

During configuration `CMAKE_PREFIX_PATH` is set to `(prefix)` as per the above directory structure. However, because `CMAKE_LIBRARY_ARCHITECTURE` is not being set, cmake configuration fails.

Another observation is that, when I force `CMAKE_LIBRARY_ARCHITECTURE` from `CMakeLists.txt` with the same `set` command (just as a test) configuration goes succeeds properly.

Is this expected behavior? How can I set `CMAKE_LIBRARY_ARCHITECTURE` to be used in the `lib` search path using a toolchain?

**Details**
Host: GNU/Linux x86_64
cmake version 3.17.2
clang version 10.0.0-4ubuntu1

Comment: `CMAKE_LIBRARY_ARCHITECTURE` is a variable CMake detects and sets this variable to the proper value (as stated in CMake documentation).  I don't believe you can override it in a toolchain file, but can override it in a CMakeLists.txt file after the `project()` command.  `CMAKE_LIBRARY_ARCHITECTURE` is probably in one of the other CMake files in the build directory; I'm not surprised its not in the cache file, its probably not meant to be overridden by a user.

Comment: I'm using a toolchain file for cross compiling to a custom Linux system (using Yocto).  When using CMake a file called CMakeCCompiler.cmake is generated during the compiler tests.  It contains `set(CMAKE_LIBRARY_ARCHITECTURE "x86_64-linux-gnu")`.  It also generates a file called `CMakeSystem.cmake` which contains `set(CMAKE_SYSTEM_PROCESSOR "x86_64")`.  It doesn't appear to be well documented the actual names CMake will use.

Comment: So far I understood that toolchains were the place to set `CMAKE_LIBRARY_ARCHITECTURE` if not auto detected. The strange thing is CMake with VS2019 using MSVC allows me to even set the variable using `CMakeSettings.json` (which I assume will build a command line eventually) and everything works as expected. The difference in behavior is very surprising.

Comment: You can set `CMAKE_LIBRARY_ARCHITECTURE` to override what CMake thinks it should be but not in a toolchain file.  That isn't what toolchain files are for.

Answer (score 0):

Currently the cmake docs for CMAKE_LIBRARY_ARCHITECTURE are kinda useless. However, if you look at the doc for find_package, it says:

> Paths with lib/ are enabled if the CMAKE_LIBRARY_ARCHITECTURE
> variable is set

Otherwise find_package/find_library don't bother searching within them. It doesn't do much else, but will suit your purpose.